# How do I create a class to sort a file in java

Tags: java

I have my program reading in the file(which contain first name and last names) from the user and printing it out. Now I need to write a method to sort the contents of the file by last name to call in the main. My question is where to begin. I started making my class for sortFile but am stuck on where to even begin.

```
package javaproject1;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;

public class JavaProject1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
    {
    String check = "y";
        do{
        Scanner fileRead = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the file: ");
        File myFile = new File(fileRead.next());
        Scanner scanTwo = new Scanner(myFile);

        while(scanTwo.hasNext())
        {
            String i = scanTwo.next();
            String j = scanTwo.next();
            String sortLast;

            System.out.println(i + " " + j + " ");
        }

        System.out.println();
        Scanner anw = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Add another? y/n ");
        check = anw.next();
        }while(check.equals("y"));
    }  

    public File sortFile(String sortLast)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a class `Person` implementing the `Comparable` interface:

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    protected String firstName;
    protected String lastName;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person o) {
        return this.lastName.compareTo(o.lastName);
    }
}
```

The class overrides the `compareTo` method, defining the sorting.

You can then store the file contents you read, in a `SortedSet<Person>` like `TreeSet`.

Assuming `i` is the first name and `j` is the last name, add the following two lines to your code:

```
String check = "y";
SortedSet<Person> persons = new TreeSet<>();
```

and

```
System.out.println(i + " " + j + " ");
persons.add(new Person(i, j));
```

`persons` will always contain the file contents you read so far, sorted by last name.

After the `}while(check.equals("y"));` you can then do a:

```
for (Person person : persons) {
    System.out.println(person);
}
```

Comment: Looks as if you are working on the same project :-) -- Just found this http://stackoverflow.com/a/28530497/1990592 which is more elegant just using an `ArrayList` and the `Comparator.comparing` method. But it requires Java 8 as far as I know.