# Java - Sorting ArrayList by string attribute from file

Tags: java, csv, arraylist, attributes

Here is what I have been trying to achieve the whole day. I currently have a class which has the attributes for my objects with setters and getters. I have another class where I read my CSV file and put it in a ArrayList. Every row of the file is a object and every column is a attribute which I have assigned and this works when I do a System.out.println.

What I now want to is create a class that can sort the objects by an attribute which is a string. How do I go about to do this as I have been trying all day using Comparators but I have no idea what I am doing.

Comment: Show us your code, samples from CSV file.

Comment: Post your code. Without it we can't show and explain mistake you made.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have a CSV file like this:

```
John,Smith,28
Jane,Doe,37
```

Etc, then we have a `class Person`, something like:

```
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;

    //getters and setters

   //equals and hashCode
}
```

We then read the file, line by line, into a `List<Person>`. We now want to sort the `List` by `lastName`. This can be done like so:

```
final List<Person> people = readFile();
people.sort(Comparator.comparing(Person::getLastName));
```

Comment: Do I put this in my main class?

Comment: @Logic210 I don't know where you put it. You haven't posted any code.